# Where does this $dy$ come from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

CONTEXT: Large Deviation Theory

Textbook: [Perspectives on Statistical Mechanics, Yoshitsugu Oono](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=nSzrAQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ja#v=onepage&q&f=false)

For i.i.d. stochastic variables $\{X_n\}$, the rate function (or large deviation function) $I(y)$ is defined in the following equation

$$P \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum _{k=1} ^N X_k \in v(y) \right) \simeq e^{-N I(y)}$$

where $v(y)$ is a volume element around $y$, and $N$ the number of samples. (The equation is [(10.24)](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=nSzrAQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ja#v=onepage&q=(10.24)&f=false) (p.112) in the book.)

and $Z(t)$ is defined as,

$$Z(t) \equiv \int P \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum _{k=1}^{N} X_k \in \mathrm dy \right) e^{N t y}$$

(This is [(18.63)](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=nSzrAQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ja#v=snippet&q=(18.63)&f=false) (p.224) in the book.)

Please note that $P$ here includes $\mathrm dy$ since $P(Y \in \mathrm dy) = \mathrm dP = f \mathrm dy$, where $f$ is probability density function.

The book says,

> From the definition of $I$, we can also write $Z$ as $$Z(t) = \int \mathrm dy e^{N(ty - I(y))}.$$

(This is (18.64).)

Where does this $\mathrm dy$ come from? Just substituting the definition doesn't create $\mathrm dy$, I think. However, $\mathrm dy$ is needed in the following discussion.

Could anyone please give me any hints?

Comment: I think your first equation needs a factor of $v(y)$ on the right side. You've said that the two sides are PROPORTIONAL, but haven't specified the constant of proportionality. Clearly the left side is proportional to $v(y)$, at least for small $v(y)$, so the right hand side should be as well.

Comment: @JahanClaes Thank you for your comment. As you say, I believe it is more natural that the RHS has the factor $v(y)$, so that $e^{-NI}$ behaves like a probability density function. Though actually this modification occurs some contradictions in another context, here I'll use the natural definition. Thank you again.